# XSLT 1.0: How can I format a paragraph over multiple lines whilst keeping a token intact?

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb, format

I want to split a long sentence onto multiple lines whilst keeping the full word at the end of a sentence. I have a line length of 40, so it should print the current word then go on to the next line if it pushes the line length over 40. All the delimiters are spaces, and I am not currently retrieving the words as tokens. This seems extremely difficult as I am limited to using XSLT 1.0.

**Example from:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut mi neque, sit amet tincidunt magna. Phasellus eleifend suscipit neque, at pretium enim facilisis non. Aenean a ornare eros.
```

**Desired example to:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean ut mi neque, sit
amet tincidunt magna. Phasellus eleifend
suscipit neque, at pretium enim facilisis
non. Aenean a ornare eros.
```

**Currently I am using an existing XSL method:**

```
<xsl:template name="nextline">
    <xsl:param name="return"/>
    <xsl:param name="width"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- when the string-length is greater than the width -->
        <xsl:when test="(string-length($return) div string-length($width)) &gt; 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($return,1,$width - 1), '&#10;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="nextline">
                <xsl:with-param name="return" select="substring($return, $width)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="$width"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- just print the string length -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($return,1,$width - 1)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**Current, undesired, example to:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
 adipiscing elit. Aenean ut mi neque, s
it amet tincidunt magna. Phasellus elei
fend suscipit neque, at pretium enim fa
cilisis non. Aenean a ornare eros.
```

**Partial solution below results in:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur

adipiscing elit. Aenean ut mi neque, sit

amet tincidunt magna. Phasellus eleifend

suscipit neque, at pretium enim facilisis

non. Aenean a ornare eros.
```

Comment: I would be sorely tempted to use an extension function for this rather than trying to code it in pure XSLT.  Given you've tagged the question "jaxb" can I assume you're running the transformation from Java?  Which XSLT processor will you be using?  It can almost certainly be done but given the existence of things like [WordUtils.wrap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//api/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (commons-lang) it seems like much pain for little gain...

Comment: Unfortunately not all the text I need to transform is inside a Java variable. To give you more context - JAXB is used to marshall an object to an XML file, and the XSL transformation is performed to create a report. Inside this report there are some short variable names and strings to supplement the data I need to transform with. The marshalled object may only contain '2.0' and '28/02/2013' whereas the transformation may need to be 'End of week total: 2.0 on 28/02/2013'. I am unsure what Java processor I'm using apart from  javax.xml.transform - I hope this gave a little more insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to use an extension function for this purpose rather than trying to code it in pure XSLT.  You say in the question that you're using `javax.xml.transform`, which by default uses Xalan under the covers, which supports Java extension functions.  Apache [commons-lang 3.1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) provides a static method [WordUtils.wrap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which appears to do exactly what you need, if you add that library to your project then you can call this as an extension as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
     xmlns:wu="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils"
     exclude-result-prefixes="wu">

  <xsl:template match=".....">
     <xsl:value-of select="wu:wrap(stringToWrap, 40)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're getting the value to wrap from an element you may need to use the `string` function, i.e. `wu:wrap(string(someElement), 40)`

Comment: So I have version 2.6 of commons-lang installed. I have an XSLT class with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wu="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils"
     exclude-result-prefixes="wu"> as the header. I have the lorem impum paragraph above defined as <xsl:variable name="testVar"> - and I am trying to test this using <xsl:value-of select="wu:wrap($testVar, 40)" />. I'm receiving a "The first argument to the non-static Java function 'wrap' is not a valid object reference" error - any thoughts?

Comment: @Schpudd you need 3.1, not 2.6. Also you probably need to provide a value for the variable, e.g. `<xsl:variable name="testVar" select="'This is a test with lots of words so it goes over 40 characters in length'"/>`

Comment: This works perfectly with `translate(wu:wrap(concat($lorem1, $lorem2, XML_1, XML2, $lorem3), 40), '&#10;','')` to get rid of the extra new line characters it generated.

Comment: @Schpudd that sounds like your "double newlines" aren't actually double newlines but CR followed by LF.  If you were to use the four argument version of WordUtils.wrap you can control this, so try `wu:wrap(concat(....), 40, '&#10;', false())`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a solution using the `str-split-to-lines` template from [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/">
 <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Lines.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-lines">
    <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="concat(/*, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="40"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut mi neque, sit amet tincidunt magna. Phasellus eleifend suscipit neque, at pretium enim facilisis non. Aenean a ornare eros.</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Lorem. ipsum dolor$ sit ame, consectetur 
adipiscing elit? Aenean ut mi neque, sit 
amet tincidunt magna. Phasellus eleifend 
suscipit neque, at pretium enim 
facilisis non. Aenean a ornare eros.
```

**Do note**:

This solution allows any (multiple-valued) characters that are considered delimiters between words, to be specified as a parameter.

Comment: Does this work with XSLT 1.0? I can only find a downloader for XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You need to download FXSL 1.x -- not FXSL 2.x.

Comment: @Schpudd, You can download FXSL 1.2 here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/fxsl/FXSL%201.2/

Comment: Ah! It seems that inside the strSplit-to-lines.xsl it's expecting a template to be "/" whereas I'm using "/REPORT". I don't wish to use this for the entire document, only as a callable template for a subset of the document at my will (i.e. the contents of the <T> block above passed in as a parameter). I have a few other formatters (align right, align centre) that I've written. I am passing in concat($loremIp1, $loremIp2, ' ') as my pStr parameter with little success - where loremIp1 and loremIp2 make a variable without newline characters.

Comment: @Schpudd, You are confused. Just pass as the `pStr` parameter any string you want.